# Google Maps API v2 shows blank map

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have set up an Android Application in order to view some things on a Google Map. I used the Google Maps API v2 and followed all the setup which can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key). I even registered the application using a key that I applied for on Google's website.
I have been able to get the Activity running but every time I open it I am greeted with a blank screen.

[image: The Blank Screen I am shown]

**This is my Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.stullich.tim.woistmeinphoto"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
    android:name="com.stullich.tim.woistmeinphoto.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.stullich.tim.woistmeinphoto.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:required="true" 
        android:name="android.test.runner"> 
    </uses-library> 
    <activity
        android:name="com.stullich.tim.woistmeinphoto.PhotoGalleryActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".FullImageViewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MapViewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Excluded this for now" />       
</application>
```

**And This Is My Activity Where I Load The Map**

```
package com.stullich.tim.woistmeinphoto;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MapViewActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.map_view_activity);

  SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
          .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
}
}
```

I have heard that not having the correct API Key used can lead to this problem, but I have triple-checked the key now and I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct key to sign your app? The API key is tied to the signing key and the application package.  If you are compiling in debug mode, make sure you have registered your eclipse debug key as well as your release key.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I also had to sign my debugging key. I will try that out and let you know.

Comment: This answer help me, for some reason Android studio hides the release key on the project window:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291977/google-maps-showing-on-emulator-but-not-on-a-device/34375396#34375396

Answer (score 2):

The [Akhil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386918/akhil) solved the issue for me as well.

I am using OSX and the debug.keystore is located in `$HOME/.android/debugkeystore`. The password for the debug.keystore is 'android' as pointed in the [Signing in Debug Mode](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode) documentation. You will need to execute keytool to get the SHA1 string

```
$> keytool -list -v -keystore .android/debug.keystore 
Enter keystore password:  

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Mar 7, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 5138a42f
Valid from: Thu Mar 07 15:29:03 CET 2013 until: Sat Feb 28 15:29:03 CET 2043
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  BA:3C:6D:7A:4C:4A:AD:3E:65:DB:53:D1:3A:23:A3:4D
     SHA1: A5:38:93:50:7C:EA:55:22:51:1E:BC:EE:AA:A5:6D:A8:6C:B7:16:35
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3
```

In the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) you would need the SHA1 string `A5:38:93:50:7C:EA:55:22:51:1E:BC:EE:AA:A5:6D:A8:6C:B7:16:35`

Comment: I can confirm this helps! I also forgot to enable maps android API in the developer console.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and found that my debug key was wrong. I changed it and now it's working.