# GoogleMap class object throw Nullpointer Exception

Tags: android, google-maps

friends, I am getting NullPointer error ,on **addMarker()**

Below is my sample code.

```
GoogleMap myMap;
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment myMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
myMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

Error message like NullPointer at line

```
myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DemoMapActiviy" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

any idea how can i solve it?

Comment: did you check if myMapFragment.getMap() returns a non null object ?

Comment: add your xml layout code

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216205/google-map-android-api-v2-sample-code-not-working

Comment: Did you use the debugger ?

Answer (score 0):

I went through this issue a while back. First check to see if your fragment is found by the fragment manager.

If not try replacing the way you've put your fragment into your view. If you want an example of another way I've posted a maps example [here](https://github.com/ChristopherTulip/MapHomeTest)

Any more questions feel free to comment and I'll work through it with you :)

**EDIT**

have you got the correct API key in there? If you can't contact Google's servers then there's a good chance that that's your problem. Otherwise may be a manifest issue make sure you have  READ_GSERVICES and INTERNET permissions.

See [Google Maps API V2 'Failed to Load Map. Could not contact Google Servers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727992/google-maps-api-v2-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-google-servers)

**Edit 2**

Ok so I was being lazy before and just referring you to my project. If you were getting a connection to maps in your project lets start from there.

What I was suggesting in my original response was to check and see if `myMapFragment` was null. If it is great try doing something along the lines of the following:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
SupportMapFragment myMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.map, myMapFragment, Constant.TAXI_FRAGMENT_ID);
ft.commit();
```

Where R.id.map is an empty `FrameLayout`

If `myMapFragment` isn't null then try extending `SupportMapFragment` and running the following test:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated()
    {
        if (getMap() == null) Log.e("TAG", "There's something very wrong here";
    }
}
```

Also if you do this make sure that you are inflating an instance of `MyMapFragment` not of `SupportMapFragment`

Comment: i check your example and varify it with my application now issues is when i run application error message give like Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.