# Android Google Map API V2 Blank Screen with zoom controls

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

My manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.yousystem.loyalties"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="10"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <permission
            android:name="com.yousystem.loyalties.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.yousystem.loyalties.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:name=".LocalApplication">
        <activity
                android:name=".LoginActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".MasterActivity"
                android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
                android:name=".PromotionsActivity"
                android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
                android:name=".NewsAndPromotionsDetailsActivity"
                android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="myKey" />
    </application>


</manifest>
```

My Fragment

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class LocationsFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        // initMap();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Blank screen with zoom controls is visible, what is wrong ?

**EDIT1:** com.yousystem.loyalties E/Google Maps Android API: Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

**EDIT2:** Fixed Edit1 error with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` 
Now I have Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.

Answer (score 2):

Its a network error. Connect your device to strong connection, Problem will be solved.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Is it a Black Screen or a grey screen? If its Grey, 99% chance you have entered an incorrect API key. Double check that. 
If the screen is Black, that is a problem with the GLSurface view maps v2 uses. Try putting the map in its own activity to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this post: [Google Map Android Api V2 Sample Code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216205/google-map-android-api-v2-sample-code-not-working), if you are completely sure you did the right steps and still see the blank screen then follow the second answer, the authentication gets cached somewhere, try to uninstall the application manually (just like you do with a normal application) then "Run" again the project.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing maps layout activity and manifest and other required files, the app should be built with the keystore provided by the Android SDK itself instead of our own keystore. Use the keystore file `%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore` (Windows) or `$HOME/.android/debug.keystore` (UNIX) with alias "androiddebugkey" and password "android".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I faced the same situation today and solved my issue by this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue. I just created new android application project and then copy pasted the all src and layout files(or can be imported), then again created new API key for new package. It did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You still have "mykey" as the value of your google maps api key.

You have to get an own key [from here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get-key) and put it there.